# Add filter-by-tag in the all posts admin console page

Tags: posts, admin, wp-admin

By default the 'all posts' page contains the following filters

- by date
- by category

Is there a way I can add 'by tags' as well ?[image]

Comment: are you want to replace categories dropdown filter with tags?

Answer (score 4):

User `'restrict_manage_posts'` filter to add another filter. Use the following code in functions.php

```
function kc_add_taxonomy_filters() {
global $typenow;

// an array of all the taxonomyies you want to display. Use the taxonomy name or slug
$my_taxonomies = array(  'post_tag' );
switch($typenow){

    case 'post':

        foreach ($my_taxonomies as $tax_slug) {


                    $tax_obj = get_taxonomy($tax_slug);
                    $tax_name = $tax_obj->labels->name;
                    $terms = get_terms($tax_slug);
                    if(count($terms) > 0) {
                        echo "<select name='$tax_slug' id='$tax_slug' class='postform alignleft actions'>";
                        echo "<option value=''>Show All $tax_name</option>";
                        foreach ($terms as $term) {
                            echo '<option value="', $term->slug,'" ',selected( @$_GET[$tax_slug] == $term->slug , $current = true, $echo = false ) , '>' , $term->name ,' (' , $term->count ,')</option>';
                        }
                        echo "</select>";
                    }

        }


    break;
}
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'kc_add_taxonomy_filters' );
```

Comment: For a little more on why this works, see the example code about the $typenow global here: https://gist.github.com/bradvin/1980309

Essentially it identifies the current post type in the WP admin.

Answer (score 0):

With absolutely no help whatsoever from this community and it's ridiculous reputation rules, I have worked out how to amend the above code so that it works properly.

The following code needs to go into *wp-includes/functions.php*. Notice that I have hardcoded the select name to be tag, which appears to be how the WP filter query string works now.

```
function kc_add_taxonomy_filters() {
global $typenow;

// an array of all the taxonomyies you want to display. Use the taxonomy name or slug
$my_taxonomies = array(  'post_tag' );
switch($typenow){

    case 'post':

        foreach ($my_taxonomies as $tax_slug) {


                    $tax_obj = get_taxonomy($tax_slug);
                    $tax_name = $tax_obj->labels->name;
                    $terms = get_terms($tax_slug);
                    if(count($terms) > 0) {
                        echo "<select name='tag' id='$tax_slug' class='postform alignleft actions'>";
                        echo "<option value=''>Show All $tax_name</option>";
                        foreach ($terms as $term) {
                            echo '<option value="', $term->slug,'" ',selected( @$_GET[$tax_slug] == $term->slug , $current = true, $echo = false ) , '>' , $term->name ,' (' , $term->count ,')</option>';
                        }
                        echo "</select>";
                    }

        }


    break;
}
}
```

Then the action needs to go into your theme functions.php file (wp-content/themes/YOURTHEME/functions.php

```
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'kc_add_taxonomy_filters' );
```

Comment: Your post appears to be the same as the one above it. Am I missing something between the two? does their's not work for some reason?

Comment: My post clarified where bits need to go because the original answer didn't work for me. But it now appears to be working fine with everything in yourtheme/functions.php so I guess my answer is no longer necessary.